# Create Azure Alert with Custom Properties in Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

So, I need to create something like 100 Alerts on all our storage accounts. As this is going to be extremely repetitive I am trying to script this.

I have the loop working that gets all the relevant storage accounts. However, I am having some issues with the creation of the Alert.

I can get the Azure Powershell to create the Alert, but I require Custom Properties to be passed in the actions as it goes to a logic app. The properties are used to decide how the alert is treated.

I have so far:

```
$actionGroupId = New-AzActivityLogAlertActionGroupObject -Id $actionGroup.Id

$availabilityCriteria = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria `
                        -MetricName "Availability" `
                        -TimeAggregation Average `
                        -Operator LessThan `
                        -Threshold 100                       


Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "********-****-****-****-***********"
$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "****-testing" -Name "storageaccount"

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$($storage.StorageAccountName) availability alert" `
                        -ResourceGroupName ****-testing `
                        -WindowSize 00:05:00 `
                        -Frequency 00:05:00 `
                        -Description "This is a test" `
                        -Condition $availabilityCriteria `
                        -ActionGroupId $actionGroupId.Id `
                        -Severity 2 `
                        -TargetResourceId $storage.Id
```

I need a custom property, the one that appears on the Action tab when creating an Alert through the Azure Portal.

[image: Custom Properties Location]

I am assuming it is something to do with the Action Group as you cant set this until you have selected an Action Group.
However, I cant find anything in the documentation that mentions the custom properties for either the New-AzActivityLogAlertActionGroupObject, New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria or Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2.

What am I missing?
Cheers

Update: I have now tried a few iterations of:

```
$actionGroup = Get-AzActionGroup
$newActionGroup = New-AzActivityLogAlertActionGroupObject -Id $actionGroup.Id -WebhookProperty = @{ "propertyName"="propertyValue"}

Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$($storage.StorageAccountName) availability alert" `
                        -ResourceGroupName ****-testing `
                        -WindowSize 00:05:00 `
                        -Frequency 00:05:00 `
                        -Description "This is a test" `
                        -Condition $availabilityCriteria `
                        -Actions $newActionGroup `
                        -Severity 2 `
                        -TargetResourceId $storage.Id
```

But I keep getting errors like this
[image: Bind Error]

Further edit: The existing Action Group and the Storage Account are in different Subscriptions.

Here is the full code including getting the ActionGroup as well as the Storage Account:

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<ActionGroupSubscriptionId>"
$existingActionGroup = Get-AzActionGroup 

$newActionGroup = New-AzActivityLogAlertActionGroupObject -Id $existingActionGroup.Id -WebhookProperty @{"sampleWebhook"="Value"} | convertFrom-json 

$availabilityCriteria = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria `
                        -MetricName "Availability" `
                        -MetricNamespace "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" `
                        -TimeAggregation Average `
                        -Operator LessThan `
                        -Threshold 100                    


Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<StorageAccountSubscriptionId>"
$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<StorageAccountResourceGroup>" -Name "<StorageAccount>"



Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$($storage.StorageAccountName) availability alert" `
                        -ResourceGroupName <StorageAccountResourceGroup> `
                        -WindowSize 00:05:00 `
                        -Frequency 00:05:00 `
                        -Description "This is a test" `
                        -Condition $availabilityCriteria `
                        -Actions $newActionGroup `
                        -Severity 2 `
                        -TargetResourceId $storage.Id
```

Comment: What is there in the availability criteria condition variable? @Shushud

Comment: I have amended the criteria variable to include the MetricNamespace from above. Now looks like this: $availabilityCriteria = New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria `
                        -MetricName "Availability" `
                        -MetricNamespace "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" `
                        -TimeAggregation Average `
                        -Operator LessThan `
                        -Threshold 100 `

Answer (score 0):

I also received the same error when I tried in my environment.

[image]

The error is due to the `json` type conversion as type of the argument `"-ActionGroup"` in `Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2` is `"Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup []`. Refer this [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9259) issue for more relevant information.

*I modified the script as below:*

```bash
$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup> -Name "<storageaccount>"
$actiongroup=New-AzActivityLogAlertActionGroupObject -Id $ActionGroupResourceId -WebhookProperty @{"sampleWebhook"="Value"} | convertFrom-json 
$availabilityCriteria=New-AzMetricAlertRuleV2Criteria -DynamicThreshold -MetricName "availability" -MetricNamespace "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" -TimeAggregation Average -Operator GreaterThan -ThresholdSensitivity Medium
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -Name "$($storage.StorageAccountName) availability alert" -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup> `                                         
                    -WindowSize 00:05:00 `
                    -Frequency 00:05:00 `
                    -Description "This is a test" `
                    -Condition $availabilityCriteria `
                    -Actions $actiongroup `
                    -Severity 2 `
                    -TargetResourceId $storage.Id
```

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however `$newActionGroup=New-AzActivityLogAlertActionGroupObject -Id $actionGroup.Id -WebhookProperty = @{"propertyName"="propertyValue"} | convertFrom-json` is throwing error: Cannot bind parameter 'ActionGroup'. Cannot convert value 
"@{actionGroupId=/subscriptions/<sub>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/microsoft.insights/actionGroups/<actiongroup>; webhookProperties=}" to type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Management.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup". Error: "Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' does not have a default constructor"

Comment: How are you retrieving the storage account? @Shushud

Comment: `Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<subscription-id>"`
`$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<resourcename>" -Name "<storageaccountname>"` The storage account and the existing action group are in different subscriptions.

Comment: In that case you need to pass subscription parameter while retrieving an action group. Did you do that? @Shushud

Comment: Did you check this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9259#issuecomment-498761252)! @Shushud

Comment: I have, but I cant see my mistake. I know it is hiding in plain sight. I have updated the question with further information and all of the script on how I am getting the Actions Group as well as the Storage Account

Comment: As you can see in the above answer, I tried with `convertfrom-json` method and it worked without any errors.

Comment: I can see that you gave `get-azactiongroup` without specifying any particular resource group. Can you try that by adding  `$ActionGroupResourceId = "ID"` directly.

Comment: Unfortunately not. @Jahnavi